# Function of at most polynomial growth and its derivative

Tags: functions, polynomials, asymptotics

I consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and differentiable.

I know moreover that both $f$ and $f'$ are of at most polynomial growth, i.e.
I use the following definition:

The function $g$ is of at most polynomial growth if there exist constants $m$ and $C$ such that
$$
|g(x)|\leq C (x^{-m} + x^m)
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

My question is:

Is there any relation in the degree of polynomial $m$ occuring in the above equation for $f$ and $f'$ if we know that that both are of at most polynomial growth?

My intuition is that if $f$ is bounded by a polynomial of degree $m$, then $f'$ is bounded by a polynomial of degree $m-1$.

Is this statement true?

Comment: Try e.g. $f\colon x\mapsto\sin(e^x)$

Comment: Such an inequqlity may fail even near $0$.

Comment: Sorry guys. I corrected my question, because earlier it was not fully correct.

Comment: so think about $\sin(x^n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement will only be true when $f(x)$ is a strictly polynomial function. This is not hard to prove using the [Power rule of differentiation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule)

However, it's not true for other non-strictly polynomial functions. We can disprove this extension by taking a simple counterexample. As rightly pointed out by someone in the comments, $f(x) = \sin (e^x)$ is a great counterexample.

Even though $f(x)$ is bounded by polynomial functions, such as $x,x^2,x^3$, etc., $f'(x)=e^x\cdot \cos x$ is obviously not, as the latter has exponential growth, which is always asymptotically greater than any polynomial function.

For further reading, check out the general trends in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which is a key tool in algorithm efficiency analysis in computer science.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You provided the example $f(x)=sin(e^x)$ and it is clear for me that its derivative is not bounded by polynomial. In my problem I assume that I know that both $f$ and $f'$ are bounded by polynomials. And now I wonder if I can say anything about connection between the degrees of polynomials that dominate $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: @MMM Consider $\sin(x^n)$.